# strongswan loads connections but cannot act on them

Tags: centos, strongswan

I have strongswan setup with a couple of connections in a Centos 7 box. When I do `strongswan restart --debug-all` it shows me that it's restarting the service and includes the connections in the output.

`[root@RFXH001 ~]# strongswan restart --debug-all
Stopping strongSwan IPsec...
Starting strongSwan 5.6.1 IPsec [starter]...
Loading config setup
  charondebug=all
Loading conn 'vodacom_smpp'
  esp=aes128-sha1!
  ike=aes128-sha1-mopd1536!
  left=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  leftfirewall=yes
  leftsubnet=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx./xx
  right=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  rightsubnet=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx./xx
  authby=secret
  auto=add
  dpdaction=restart
  dpddelay=10
  dpdtimeout=120
  ikelifetime=24h
  keyexchange=ikev1
  keyingtries=1
  keylife=1h
  rekey=yes
  rekeymargin=3m
  type=tunnel
Loading conn 'vodacom_ussd'
  esp=aes128-sha1!
  ike=aes128-sha1-mopd1536!
  left=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  leftfirewall=yes
  leftsubnet=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx
  right=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  rightsubnet=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx
  authby=secret
  auto=add
  dpdaction=restart
  dpddelay=10
  dpdtimeout=120
  ikelifetime=24h
  keyexchange=ikev1
  keyingtries=1
  keylife=1h
  rekey=yes
  rekeymargin=3m
  type=tunnel
found netkey IPsec stack`

But when I do `strongswan statusall` it says it has 0 connections, and when I try to `up/down/route` any of those connections by name it says `no config named 'name-of-connection'`

`[root@RFXH001 ~]# strongswan statusall
Status of IKE charon daemon (strongSwan 5.6.1, Linux 3.10.0-514.6.1.el7.x86_64, x86_64):
  uptime: 107 seconds, since Apr 15 15:15:32 2018
  malloc: sbrk 1622016, mmap 0, used 555440, free 1066576
  worker threads: 11 of 16 idle, 5/0/0/0 working, job queue: 0/0/0/0, scheduled: 0
  loaded plugins: charon pkcs11 tpm aesni aes des rc2 sha2 sha1 md4 md5 mgf1 random nonce x509 revocation constraints acert pubkey pkcs1 pkcs8 pkcs12 pgp dnskey sshkey pem openssl gcrypt fips-prf gmp curve25519 chapoly xcbc cmac hmac ctr ccm gcm curl attr kernel-netlink resolve socket-default farp stroke vici updown eap-identity eap-sim eap-aka eap-aka-3gpp eap-aka-3gpp2 eap-md5 eap-gtc eap-mschapv2 eap-dynamic eap-tls eap-ttls eap-peap xauth-generic xauth-eap xauth-pam xauth-noauth dhcp led duplicheck unity counters
Listening IP addresses:
  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Connections:
Security Associations (0 up, 0 connecting):
  none`

`[root@RFXH001 ~]# strongswan up vodacom_smpp
no config named 'vodacom_smpp'`

Have you ever had this issue? And how did you go around it?

Relevant configs

```
charon {
    load_modular = yes
    duplicheck.enable = no
    install_routes = yes
    compress = yes
    plugins {
            include strongswan.d/charon/*.conf
    }

    # two defined loggers
    filelog {
            /var/log/charon.log {
                    time_format = %b %e %T
                    ike_name = yes
                    append = no
                    default = 0
                    flush_line = yes
            }
            stderr {
                    ike = 2
                    knl = 3
            }
    }

    syslog {
            identifier = charon-custom
            daemon {
            }
            auth {
                    default = -1
                    ike = 0
            }
    }
}

include strongswan.d/*.conf
```

Comment: I've edited the description as to include the details

Comment: Thanks, Paulo. Does Vodacom not block IPsec? Vodafone used to block it here in the past.

Comment: No. I've used this very setup 4 times before with success. The only thing that is different this time is I'm using Centos where before I was using Ubuntu. Also, I think that at least I should be able to reference the connections by name and have them be recognized by the service even if I cannot establish them.

Comment: Does restarting ipsec from the command line fixes this? (try it)

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't. I've tried restarting the service and well as the server itself and it didn't get the service to work.

Comment: There is a known (old) bug that goes away after a restart. However I remember something else. When was the last time you did this? Most OSs are not supporting SHA1 anymore. I would advise SHA2 or SHA256 at least and IKEv2 while you are at it.

Comment: The output you see in `ipsec restart` is just starter logging some stuff about the configs it loaded from ipsec.conf. Whether these are successfully passed to the daemon is not logged, check the daemon log for that (but it would seem it doesn't work correctly as you'd otherwise see the loaded connections in the `Connections:` section of `ipsec statusall`).

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I'm doing this today. I tried to check the supported algorithms with `strongswan listalgs`, `SHA1` is listed & the plugin was loaded. Just to make sure I tried switching to `3des-sha2-modp1024` but still, the connections were not picked up. 
`encryption: AES_CBC[aesni] AES_CTR[aesni] 3DES_CBC[des] DES_CBC[des] DES_ECB[des] ...
integrity:  AES_XCBC_96[aesni] AES_CMAC_96[aesni] HMAC_MD5_96[openssl] HMAC_MD5_128[openssl] HMAC_SHA1_96[openssl] HMAC_SHA1_128[openssl] HMAC_SHA1_160[openssl] HMAC_SHA2_256_128[openssl] HMAC_SHA2_256_256[openssl]...`

Comment: @ecdsa the most odd thing is that the deamon log (`charon.log`) is empty. I have posted the contents of the strongswan.conf above that include configuration for logging

Comment: @ecdsa actually the logs going to `/var/log/messages`: `charon-custom: 05[CFG] received stroke: add connection 'vodacom_smpp'; charon-custom: 05[CFG] left nor right host is our side, assuming left=local; algorithm 'sha2' not recognized; charon-custom: 05[CFG] skipped invalid proposal string: 3des-sha2-mopd1024; charon-custom: 07[CFG] received stroke: add connection 'vodacom_ussd'; charon-custom: 07[CFG] left nor right host is our side, assuming left=local; charon-custom: 07[CFG] algorithm 'mopd1536' not recognized; charon-custom: 07[CFG] skipped invalid proposal string: aes128-sha1-mopd1536`

Comment: So I had written `mopd` instead of `modp` and that is why it wasn't working. After the change, restarting adds and lists the connections. Thanks so much for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had a typo in the connection configure, I had written `mopd` instead of `modp`. After the change that, restarting the service added the connections and listed them.

Thanks so much for the help